Chrome: performance memory property vs memory snapshot vs task manager memory
performance.memory
snapshot
Performance.memory shows that the currently used jsHeapSize is 259MB, but the memory snapshot shows only 120MB. What is the difference between them?
By the way, should the memory usage of JS in Chrome Task Manager be the same as the snapshot?
task-manager
waht's the difference between the three
